# using awk to print header name and a substring

Tags: bash, unix, bioinformatics, genome, google-genomics

i try using this code for printing a header of a gene name and then pulling a substring based on its location but it doesn't work

```
>output_file
cat input_file | while read row; do
        echo $row > temp
        geneName=`awk '{print $1}' tmp`
        startPos=`awk '{print $2}' tmp`
        endPOs=`awk '{print $3}' tmp`
                for i in temp; do
                echo ">${geneName}" >> genes_fasta ;
                echo "awk '{val=substr($0,${startPos},${endPOs});print val}' fasta" >> genes_fasta
        done
done
```

input_file

```
nad5_exon1 250405 250551
nad5_exon2 251490 251884
nad5_exon3 195620 195641
nad5_exon4 154254 155469
nad5_exon5 156319 156548
```

fasta

```
atgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgc............
```

and this is my wrong output file

```
>
awk '{val=substr(pull_genes.sh,,);print val}' unwraped_carm_mt.fasta
>
awk '{val=substr(pull_genes.sh,,);print val}' unwraped_carm_mt.fasta
>
awk '{val=substr(pull_genes.sh,,);print val}' unwraped_carm_mt.fasta
>
awk '{val=substr(pull_genes.sh,,);print val}' unwraped_carm_mt.fasta
>
awk '{val=substr(pull_genes.sh,,);print val}' unwraped_carm_mt.fasta
>
awk '{val=substr(pull_genes.sh,,);print val}' unwraped_carm_mt.fasta
```

output should look like that:

```
>name1
atgcatgcatgcatgcatgcat
>name2
tgcatgcatgcatgcat
>name3
gcatgcatgcatgcatgcat
>namen....
```

Comment: An example of both the input file (with a handful of cases) and the expected result would be useful to get a better sense of what you're trying to accomplish, here.

Comment: added that info in the question. thank you!

Comment: Looks good, but a "correct" output of what you would actually like it do to would also be invaluable, as I'm still not following what you're trying to accomplish. Also, your `awk` lines setting your variables are looking at `tmp`, but the file you create is called `temp`.

Comment: please fix issues found by https://shellcheck.net and then update your Q with required output from sample input. You know that can all be one `awk` process, rather than 5-6 per line of data? See http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Good luck.

Comment: You need to remove the "echo" and double quotes from the following `echo "awk '{val=substr($0,${startPos},${endPOs});print val}' fasta"`. This is a command right? If you put echo it simply prints the command and appends to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made it work!
this is the script for pulling substrings from a fasta file

```sh
cat genes_and_bounderies1 | while read row; do
        echo $row > temp
        geneName=`awk '{print $1}' temp`
        startPos=`awk '{print $2}' temp`
        endPos=`awk '{print $3}' temp`
        length=$(expr $endPos - $startPos)
                for i in temp; do
                echo ">${geneName}" >> genes_fasta
                awk -v S=$startPos -v L=$length '{print substr($0,S,L)}' unwraped_${fasta} >> genes_fasta
        done
done
```

Comment: Good, glad you got it working. But look closely at the number of subshells spawned per-iteration. For each iteration of your while loop, you call `awk` 3-times before your loop `for i in temp; do` and then once per iteration there.. Nothing wrong with making it work first, but with a million rows to read, the difference in time to execute would be hours verses seconds.

Comment: how would you suggest writing it? i'm a biologist not a programmer and would really like to learn!

Comment: The way I wrote it up in my answer. You see there is only a single-process (single subshell) spawned to run one instance of `awk` for the entire project. In your code you call `awk` a minimum of 4-times per-iteration. The program startup time alone along with loading and unloading the data used by each process will add orders of magnitude of runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a single call to `awk` which will be orders of magnitude more efficient than looping in a shell script and calling `awk` 4-times per-iteration. Since you have bash, you can simply use *command substitution* and redirect the contents of `fasta` to an `awk` variable and then simply output the heading and the substring containing the beginning through ending characters from your `fasta` file.

For example:

```
awk -v fasta=$(<fasta) '{print ">" $1; print substr(fasta,$2,$3-$2+1)}' input
```

or using `getline` within the `BEGIN` rule:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline fasta<"fasta"}
{print ">" $1; print substr(fasta,$2,$3-$2+1)}' input
```

**Example Input Files**

Note: the beginning and ending values have been reduced to fit within the 129 characters of your example:

```
$ cat input
rad5_exon1 1 17
rad5_exon2 23 51
rad5_exon3 110 127
rad5_exon4 38 62
rad5_exon5 59 79
```

and the first 129-characters of your example `fasta`

```
$ cat fasta
atgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgc
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -v fasta=$(<fasta) '{print ">" $1; print substr(fasta,$2,$3-$2+1)}' input
>rad5_exon1
atgcatgcatgcatgca
>rad5_exon2
gcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatg
>rad5_exon3
tgcatgcatgcatgcatg
>rad5_exon4
tgcatgcatgcatgcatgcatgcat
>rad5_exon5
gcatgcatgcatgcatgcatg
```

Look thing over and let me know if I understood your question requirements. Also let me know if you have further questions on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, how about:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {fasta = fasta $0; next}
    {
        printf(">%s %s\n", $1, substr(fasta, $2, $3 - $2 + 1))
    }' fasta input_file > genes_fasta
```

- It first reads `fasta` file and stores the sequence in a variable `fasta`.
- Then it reads `input_file` line by line, extracts the substring of `fasta` starting at `$2` and of length `$3 - $2 + 1`. (Note that the 3rd argument to `substr` function is length, not endpos.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ZivAttia Can you be specific about `still not working`?

Comment: 'awk '{val=substr($0,"$startPos","$endPos");print val}' unwraped_${fasta} >> genes_fasta     doesn't work for some reason. if i change the startPos and endPos to numbers it works fine

Comment: it didn't work and now I need to fix only this line

Comment: As I've commented in my answer, the 3rd argument to `substr` function is length, not the position.

Comment: ok, for some reason it is not working for me. i try using this command awk -v b="$startPos" -v c="$endPos"  '{val=substr($0,$b,$c);print val}' unwraped_${fasta} >> genes_fasta but it doesn't work either. how can i set a variable in an awk command?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to switch to awk-only solution if you are not sure how to pass shell variables to awk including its efficiency. If my answer does not work (I don't know why), please try David Rankin's solution.